# In an update function during the validation with custom rules ignore current id for duplicates in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, controller

I am using Laravel 6. I created a form to update a meeting and also some validation rules in the controller that check if the room is free at that time and if the participants are already occupied in another meeting at that time. Unfortunately when I submit the form and I change for example only the description of the meeting, the validation process doesn't work correctly because it says that the current room is already occupied at that time and also the participants are already occupied in another meeting at that time... that occurs because the validation process doesn't exclude to check the current id of the meeting. So the meeting is a duplicate of itself.

I tried many ways to change the validate method excluding the $id passed as second argument to the function update_meeting but they didn't work.

**Controller:**

```
public function update_meeting(Request $request, $id)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'participants' => [ 'required', new CheckParticipant() ], 
        'description' => 'required',
        'room' => [ 'required', new CheckRoom() ],
        'date_meeting' => [ 'required', new CheckDateTime() ],
        'start' => [ 'required', new CheckTime() ],
        'end' => 'required',
    ]);

    $meeting = Meeting::find($id);

    $participants = request('participants');
    $meeting->id_participants = implode(';', $participants);

    $meeting->description = request('description');
    $meeting->id_room = request('room');
    $meeting->date = request('date_meeting');
    $meeting->start_hour = request('start');
    $meeting->end_hour = request('end');

    $meeting->save();

    $message_correct = "The meeting has been correctly updated!";

    return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', $message_correct);

}
```

**A Custom Rule (CheckRoom):**

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{

    $meetings = DB::table('meetings')
    ->where('id_room', request('room'))
    ->where('date', request('date_meeting'))
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where(function($sub_q) {
                $sub_q->where('start_hour', '>=', request('start'))
                        ->where('start_hour', '<', request('end'));
            })
            ->orWhere(function($sub_q) {
                $sub_q->where('start_hour', '<', request('start'))
                        ->where('end_hour', '>=', request('end'));
            })
            ->orWhere(function($sub_q) {
                $sub_q->where('end_hour', '>', request('start'))
                        ->where('end_hour', '<=', request('end'));
            });
    })->get();

    if(count($meetings) > 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to ignore current id in the validate method or should I modify the rule excluding the id in the query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in this way here in my case my field is username and table name id admins and the id to ignored is $id

```
   'username'=>'required|unique:admins,username,'.$id
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the value in the constructor? `new CheckRoom($id)`

```
class CheckRoom implements Rule
{
    protected $excludeId = null;

    public function __construct($id = null)
    {
        $this->excludeId = $id;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return DB::table('meetings')
            ...
            ->when($this->excludeId, function ($query, $exclude) {
                $query->where('id', '<>', $exclude);
            })->doesntExist();
    }

    ...
}
```